# getting value by only referring to the object

Tags: java, class, object, object-oriented-analysis

How is that sometimes we get a value from the object by only referring to its name?

Example:

```
class Abc {
 int a=0; 
char b='a';

void tellDetails()
{ return a; }

void main(){
Abc obj=new Abc();
Date d1=new Date();
System.out.println(obj.a);
System.out.println(d1); }
```

As you can see for the object 'obj' I need to use a dot operator and refer to a field/method but for the 'Date' object, I can directly use the object name/reference 'd1' and not attach any field/method. Why is this so ?

Comment: Override the `toString` method defined in the `Object` class to return a String describing the object.

Answer (score 1):

Every java class have a toString method . toString method is defined in Object class and since all java classes are subclass of Object class thus every java class have a toString function in it.

When ever we try to print an object actually toString method of that class is called which return a string and that String is printed.

In your case when you print the object of Date class,toString method of date class is called.

You can also try this with you object ,just write

```
System.out.println(obj);
```

And what you will see is a String which you will not understand.
If you want to customise the toString method then you could override it as follows.

```
    class Abc {
     int a=0; 
    char b='a';

    void tellDetails()
    {
     return a; 
    }
    @Override
      public String toString()
      {
         return "a="+a+"  b="+b;
       }
    void main(){
    Abc obj=new Abc();
    Date d1=new Date();
    System.out.println(obj.a);
    System.out.println(d1); 
   }



}
```

Above code will print the value of a and b  when you will print the object of ABC class

Comment: _When ever we try to print an object actually toString method of that class is called which return a string and that String is printed._ Well actually, that's partially true. The method [`PrintStream.print(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.Object-) is documented to use [`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) that will use `Object.toString` if it is not null. The difference is that this behavior prevent NPE where your explanation didn't

Comment: I have added an answer with the explanation (not easy in comment ;) )

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is using the method [`PrintStream.print(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.Object-).

> Prints an object. The string produced by the *String.valueOf(Object)* method is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

It will internally use [`String.valueOf(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) on the parameter.

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of *obj.toString()* is returned.

So if the instance you pass don't override `toString` method, it will use the one from `Object`.

In short, you just need to override `public String toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must know that [Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the mother of every java classes, including all its methods. One of them is [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), which returns a string representation of the object. As you could notice, printing `obj` return the `classname + @ + hashcode` (Object class implementation) of the objects, like this: `Abc@7852e922`

But that's not what we need. It depends on the implementation and requirements, but most of time you are going to need object attributes with their corresponding values.

An example, in this case, could be:

***Abc class:***

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Abc {
    int a = 0;
    char b = 'a';

    int tellDetails() {
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Abc obj = new Abc();
        Date d1 = new Date();
        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(d1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Abc [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + "]";
    }
}
```

*Note: notice the @Override annotation*

Giving the following output:

```
Abc [a=0, b=a]
Fri Jun 08 03:02:27 CLT 2018
```

But now: ***How is that working for Date by default?***. Because it's **already overridden** in the [Date class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.toString%28%29). which will convert this Date object to a String of the form:

```
 dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

That's why `System.out.println(d1);` is working by default.

Comment: If you want to access specific field of Date() you can use  d1.getTime() like a normal access.

Comment: Exactly @PrashantPalve. For further understanding OP could check Date class implementation. [Date.java#Date.toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.toString%28%29)